# Maximo Anywhere login issue

Tags: authentication, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I have installed maximo-anywhere version 7.6.3. This is just a development environment using the simulator with mobilefirst on eclipse.

I am currently unable to login with the following message. Not authorized when logging into Maximo Anywhere - on other environments I have created I have just given the user the correct security group... however in this scenario even though I have deployed the WorkExecution application and provided the user with the ANYWHERE_TECHNICIAN security group the user is still unable to login.

Any thoughts? Has anyone come across this issue?

[Login failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ngK4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to HTTP/HTTPS. It looks like anywhere is currently unable to go over HTTPS.

The error message was just a rogue message throwing it off.

Thanks